# Crop image with aspect ratio doesn't take into account the context

Tags: php, google-vision

I'm trying to crop an image with Google Vision API in php. The API returns the best crop possible, **without taking into account the aspect ratio** I'm sending in.

Here is what I have so far:

```php
    $imageAnnotator = new ImageAnnotatorClient();

    $image = file_get_contents(storage_path('test.jpg'));
    $context = new \Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\ImageContext();
    $cropHintsParams = new \Google\Cloud\Vision\V1\CropHintsParams();
    $cropHintsParams->setAspectRatios([floatval(1)]);
    $context->setCropHintsParams($cropHintsParams);

    $response = $imageAnnotator->cropHintsDetection($image, [$context]);
    $annotations = $response->getCropHintsAnnotation();
```

Any idea what is wrong with this ?

The php documentation example doesn't provide any aspect ratio... https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-crop-hints

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does crop has anything to do with aspect ratio? I mean, it will only crop the image, not resize it, or am I wrong?

Comment: It evaluates the best crop for the aspect ratio you are looking for. [Google's python tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/crop-hints) is more complete on this point, but I still don't get it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, After 2 hours of diving deep into [Google libs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php), turns out the imageContext needs to be provided in an associative array like below:

```php
$response = $imageAnnotator->cropHintsDetection($im, ['imageContext' => $context]);
```

Hope this will save future somebody some time :)